# Use Ajax Filtering and non-Ajax Filtering on the same Tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Ajax to load data into my Tabulator table. The table has multiple columns, including date columns. I would like to filter some columns in standard, on the fly way (not going back to the server). However, for the date columns, I would like to go back to the server (and set initial params for this, so that we only load records for the last month). I have read the documentation, but can't see how you can set Ajax filtering on only some columns.

With that in mind, how can I trigger a reload (going back to the server) of the data if one of my custom datepicker element changes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With filtering im afraid that it can be one or the other but not both. Due to the way the filter system works it is not possible to selectively choose to filter some columns via ajax and others not.

If you wanted to implement that, i would suggest that you build your filter elements outside of the table. use them to make a ajax requests to get the filtered data, then pass that data into the table using the ***setData*** function and then apply the local filters in the table

Comment: Thank you Oli. That's exactly what I have started to implement, and it's working well. Tabulator is an incredible product - very, very well done, and thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, it is always great to hear that Tabulator is appreciated